# Tkinter unwanted padding in the x-axis

Tags: python, tkinter

Good morning guys! So I have just started learning Tkinter today and whilst applying the knowledge I learned I encountered a problem, I cannot get rid of an annoying padding in the x-axis. I tried setting the Label parameter "padx = 0" but it did not do the trick. Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

# Create a window object
app = Tk()
app.title('Gestion des locataires')
app.geometry('700x350')

# GUI
# Nom et prenom
nom_text = StringVar()
nom_text = Label(app, text='Nom', font=('bold', 14), pady=20, padx=0)
nom_text.grid(row=0, column=0)

prenom_text = StringVar()
prenom_text = Label(app, text='Prénom', font=('bold', 14), pady=20, padx=0)
prenom_text.grid(row=1, column=0)

# Start program
app.mainloop()
```

I hope you can help me understand where the problem is. Have a blessed morning.

Comment: use `sticky='w'` in the `grid` method, by default widgets are centered in their row and column and the first column (0) is as wide as the widest widget in it and so the less wide widgets are centered, so use sticky to make the widget stick to a side (you can use also make it stick to more than one side) so an alternative could be to use `sticky='we'` in the `grid` method and `anchor='w'` for the `Label`

Comment: I already explained, the column (without configuration) is as wide as the widest widget, so since the other label is wider its center is at the same place as the column's center